# SimpleXMLElement object parsing

Tags: php, xml

i have xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<comments
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <authors>
        <author></author>
    </authors>
    <commentList>
        <comment authorId="0" ref="G2">
            <text>
                <t xml:space="preserve"> test comment 1</t>
            </text>
        </comment>
        <comment authorId="0" ref="G4">
            <text>
                <t xml:space="preserve"> test comment 2</t>
            </text>
        </comment>
    </commentList>
</comments>
```

i load it through SimpleXMLElement  php function

```
$com = new SimpleXMLElement('data.xml');
```

when i print_r($com) i get

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [authors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                ()
        )
    [commentList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [authorId] => 0
                                    [ref] => G2
                                )
                            [text] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                ([t] => test comment 1)
                        )
                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [authorId] => 0
                                    [ref] => G4
                                )
                            [text] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [t] => test comment 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

i want to read comments using ref   values , i tried to read value of G2 like

```
echo $value = (string) $comments->commentList->comment[0]->ref['G2'];
```

but no success , any idea how to read values through ref values like G2 , G4

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the `ref` attribute or are you trying to find comments where the `ref` attribute matches a specific value?

Comment: ya want to find comment where ref value match like G2  G4 then need to read comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the comment text related to any comments that have `ref="G2"`, then you'll do this.  Iterate through each comment element, get the value of the `ref` attribute, check it against the target value, and if it matches, get the text value.

```
$xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($myXML);

foreach($xmlElement->commentList->comment as $comment)
{
    if($comment["ref"] == "G2")
    {
        echo $comment->text->t;
        // optionally echo line break or some other formatting
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/715eff1e2f0b6d7592c2bb81ce6c6312388ca848)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath to fetch the comment texts filtered by the attribute:

```
$comments = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$comments->registerXpathNamespace(
  'ofm', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main'
);

$texts = $comments->xpath('ofm:commentList/ofm:comment[@ref="G2"]/ofm:text');
foreach ($texts as $text) {
  var_dump((string)$text->t);
}
```

Output:

```
string(15) " test comment 1"
```

Your XML uses a default namespace, so for Xpath you will have to register and use a prefix.

DOM would not be much different for that:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace(
  'ofm', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main'
);

$texts = $xpath->evaluate(
  '/ofm:comments/ofm:commentList/ofm:comment[@ref="G2"]/ofm:text'
);
foreach ($texts as $text) {
  var_dump($text->textContent);
}
```